# regarding storing multiple values

Tags: java

I have made the hash table below but Now I am trying to store multiple values with the same key but I am unable to do that please advise how to achieve that and then how to iterate overit to show the values attached with the multiple key..

```
Hashtable companies = new Hashtable();
// Java Hashtable example to put object into Hashtable
// put(key, value) is used to insert object into map
companies.put("Google", "United States");
companies.put("Nokia", "Finland");
companies.put("Sony", "Japan");
```

I want to achieve like ..

```
Hashtable companies = new Hashtable();
// Java Hashtable example to put object into Hashtable
// put(key, value) is used to insert object into map
companies.put("Google", "United States","France");
companies.put("Nokia", "Finland","Japan");
companies.put("Sony", "Japan", "indonesia");
```

folks please advise ..!!

Comment: Use a [Guava Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [guava mutlimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) (or) change your value to one of List implementation instead of `String` and better to use HashMap than HashTable.

Example:

```
Map<String, List<String>> = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map of lists...

```
Map<String, List<String>> companies = new Hashtable<String, List<String>>();
companies.put("Google", Arrays.asList("United States","France")); //etc...
```

Comment: @Zuti on the left hand side you have mention Map but on the right hand side you are saying hashtable please advise

Comment: `Hashtable` implements the `Map` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Don;t use hashtable, use hashmap, you could just change the structure to this :

```
Map<String, List<String>>
```

Comment: Please advise how can I change the structure , Please post the code..!

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `Hashtable`, use a `HashMap`.
- If you use Guava (which you should, really ;)), use a `Multimap`.
- If you don't, use a `HashTable<String, List<String>>`; you will need a wrapper class however so that you create the `List` in the key before you can add to that list.